# useEffect with dependency array triggers multiple times because of array.map

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm creating a simple React application where a parent component renders a number of children components based on an input range slider (using array.map).

I'm performing certain actions within a useEffect with a dependency array in the child component (particularly, I'm obtaining a 3D model's bounding box size using react-three-fiber). Even though I have the dependency array, I can see from the console logs that the useEffect executes each time I move the slider.

How can I ensure that this useEffect only executes once? I was considering passing the useRef of the model to the parent and doing the useEffect actions there, but I'm curious if there's a way to modify useEffect such that it just executes once.

Comment: Depends on what kind of range slider you're using, but in general you probably want to use something like `onMouseUp` rather than `onChange`, so it's only executed one you let go on the final value

Comment: Thanks for replying! That works for me. I've also tried useMemo solution, but my point is I want to understand why this happens, so I used useRef to see what changes in the data.

Comment: Well `onChange` fires literally every time the value changes, so as you're dragging it along, every little bit it moves fires that `onChange` event. Whereas `onMouseUp`, you can drag the slider up and down, and **NO** functions are triggered until you let that mouse button go, at which point the slider is at it's final, desired value.

Comment: Yes, I got what did you mean Thanks for your explanation. I chose to use useMemo as it runs a function and returns its result. But if useMemo's dependency array didn't change, it doesn't run the function and just uses the previous result. This is helpful when you don't want to run a slowass function many times, or don't want to create a new array every render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a deep understanding of my needs, one of the arguments was changing.

Functions not through a useCallback will always change. Rebuilt objects (and to some extent, arrays) are new as well (unless memoized).

I checked what is changing first. Instead of using useRef, figure out what is changing in the data.

But in reality, if that dependency was actually needed, I can memoize it (e.g. [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo)) instead of just removing it.